# grails create-script - how to find out appName?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

How do I get appName in a custom grails script? I've tried including `_GrailsSettings`,`_GrailsCompile`, and `_GrailsInit`, but nothing lets `${appName}` resolve. I'm assuming I'm missing some basic include to set this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`metadata.'app.name'` is what you're looking for.